# ampersand not passing through url

Tags: javascript, html, url, ampersand

On  my site [www.gibberize.com](http://www.gibberize.com) if you type in the word "and" in the top textarea, the character "&" will appear in the second textarea.

The problem is that the "tweet it" link will then append the second textarea's text to a url and proceed to the link, but because it is an ampersand it will break the text.

Any solutions?

Comment: What language are you doing back end coding in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's `urlencode()` function.

Comment: Oh, that's of course assuming you're using PHP. Sorry about that.

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway because conversion is all client side.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The point is that the tweet is sent in an URL.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function. You could just change it to `%26` yourself, but it's safer to use the function provided, as that will take care of any other odd characters that might get messed up in transmission.

Comment: also best set `element.href=` directly; don't use `setAttribute`, which is less readable and bugged in various ways in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, escape the ampersand symbol before appending the tweet, change any & for %26. You may want to

> encodeURIComponent()

the whole text.

Note: original function I suggested was escape().

Comment: `escape` is inappropriate for URL-encoding; EncodeURIComponent is correct. `escape` shouldn't really be used for anything.